# Where do I find the nine (9) patch png file for Android's default scroll thumb?

Tags: android, scrollview, nine-patch, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I am looking for the nine (9) patch PNG file that android uses as its default scroll thumb.  Also known as that little grey bar on the right that changes shape depending on the amount of content in the ScrollView.  I would like to have the file in my hands rather than re-creating it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search here: \platforms\android-N\data\res. For example, there is a file scrollbar_handle_accelerated_anim2.9